# Typo in user rep league?

Tags: support, wording, reputation-leagues

There might be a small typo [here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/month/meta/2022-07-01/1121369#1121369). It reads:

> "month change"

Should it not read:

> "monthly change"

This should be the same for "year" - "yearly" etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because it refers to a specific month — namely the current one — and not to an average month, which your suggested phrasing would imply.

This phrasing is a shortened form of "*the change that has occurred this month*", or something to that effect.
Similarly, "*year rank*" is "*the user's rank for this (or the specified) year*".